# Setting a variable's value directly from a function

Tags: php, function

```
<?
        function reg_valid_email(){
        if (isset($_POST['register_form_email'])) {
            global $mysqli;
            return $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['register_form_email']);
        }
    }

    $email->reg_valid_email();
?>
```

Trying to set the value of a function, using the return of a function, but I get error -> Call to a member function reg_valid_email() on string. I'm doing this for first time, so I'm doing something wrong, but can't figure out what is it. // $mysqli is my connection to db

Comment: That's because `$email` is a string, not an object.

Comment: think you need to set `global $_POST;` as 1st row inside of the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `$email` must be an object of a class in which the function `reg_valid_email` needs to be defined. But since your code snippet has not mentioned any class, just call your function `reg_valid_email` like below without the `$email`:

```
reg_valid_email();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use if ou want to store the function return

```
 $email=eg_valid_email();
 if($email!=NULL)
 {
```